# NodeJS - How to get a user automatically logged in after registration is completed

Tags: node.js, express

I want a user to directly get logged in after the registration.
I've been trying "redirect"

Comment: Could you share your registration code? Might be helpful to give you a pertinent answer

Comment: Is the nodejs your API backend ? Or are you making a ssr app ? Please explain about your project and share relevant code structures with us.